# Programmatically initiate Conference call on IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, communication

Is there a way to make a conference call programmatically on the IPhone ?

I want to be able to place a call to persons A and B, connecting both, and then dropping myself and let the two parties continue the conversation.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. An app can place a call to a single phone number, via the `-openURL:` method on `UIApplication`, but once it does that, it goes into the background and the Phone app takes over.

Also, it sounds as if you’re trying to make a prank-calling app, which is in violation of section **22.6** of the App Store Review Guidelines:

> Apps that enable anonymous or prank phone calls or SMS/MMS messaging will be rejected

Answer (score 1):

That type of calling you described in your question, can only happen if you are on a phone system (PBX) in a office.  On a mobile phone or the phone in your house, once the party that initiated both calls hangs up, everyone is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Facetime if you aren't one of the two persons. But, you would a audio conference or a video conference ?