# Conference calling from iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

do Apple support for making a conference call? I have search alot but have not found any tutorial or link which can guide me or help me in making conference call from my iPhone Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not possible. An app can place a call to a single phone number, via
>   the `-openURL:` method on `UIApplication`, but once it does that, it
>   goes into the background and the Phone app takes over.

Please see: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457170/programmatically-initiate-conference-call-on-iphone)

Comment: Thank you SimpkeBob after your answer my searching for Conference calling comes to an end... :)